# Firebase database not loading images in image slider

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, androidimageslider

I have made this program to retrieve images from firebase database in image slider but it is showing error in addListenerForSingleValueEvent and when checking error it generate some kind of private function but then also after running the app it is not showing anything it is coming blank.

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var imageSlider: ImageSlider
    lateinit var ref: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
      
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Slider")

        imageSlider = findViewById<ImageSlider>(R.id.imageslider)
        val remoteimages: List<SlideModel> = ArrayList()

           ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (h in snapshot.children)
                        remoteimages.add(SlideModel(
                                h.child("url").getValue().toString(),
                                h.child("title").getValue().toString(),
                                ScaleTypes.FIT))

                    imageSlider.setImageList(remoteimages, ScaleTypes.FIT)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if your getting value or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking error it generates some kind of private function"? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo - App is not crashing . when we hoverover on add in this line (remoteimages.add(SlideModel).... it asks to generate private function and after generating -  no error comes  but also no image loaded in image slider